# Change installation path programmatically and show on "Confirm Installation" dialogue of setup project - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, setup-project

In my setup project I am not showing the `Installation Folder` dialogue. I would like to change the `Product Name` programmatically which in turn should change the default installation location and then show it on the `Confirm Installation` dialogue.

Can this be done? If so how? Numerous searches have returned nothing of use.

Answer (score 0):

Most of this can't be done directly with Visual Studio setups, or any others, because Windows Installer doesn't support changing ProductName after the install has started.

You could do the install location part with a launcher program that asked for that information and started the MSI install with a command line naming the target install directory. To change the product name you can't really open the MSI programmatically to change the ProductName (in the Property table) because the MSI file might be in a read-only location, and altering the MSI file would damage its integrity if it's signed. Transforms are the normal way to change the content of an MSI file at install time. A search on creating a transform file would show you how to do this, and this might help:

http://www.contactez.net/support/MSITransform.html

The general idea would be to have your launcher program ask for the install directory and the product name, then create a transform file programmatically, then apply it by the installing the MSI with TARGETDIR=[PATH] TRANSFORMS=[path to mst].

Showing the install directory on the confirmation dialog is straightforward enough with Windows Installer dialogs, but Visual Studio setups don't have any support for it.